# Same sampler, multiple texture units, OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures

With OpenGL (core profile, 4.4), is it "legal" to bind the same sampler object to 2 different texture units at the same time?

My test shows it works, but I don't know if my driver is being forgiving or if it's a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable as discussed below.

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf)  -  *8.2 Sampler Objects*  -  pp. 164-165

> #### 8.2 Sampler Objects
>
> > When a sampler object is bound to a texture unit, its state supersedes that of
> >     the texture object bound to that texture unit. If the sampler name zero is bound to
> >     a texture unit, the currently bound texture’s sampler state becomes active. ***A single
> >     sampler object may be bound to multiple texture units simultaneously.***
> >
> > A sampler object binding is effected with the command:
> >
> > > `void glBindSampler (GLuint unit, GLuint sampler);`
> >
> > with `unit` set to the zero-based index of the texture unit to which to bind the sampler
> >     and `sampler` set to the name of a sampler object returned from a previous call to
> >     **`glGenSamplers`**.
> >
> > If the bind is successful no change is made to the state of the bound sampler
> >     object, and any previous binding to unit is broken.